# When copy-pasting graphic from one LyX file to another, "../" is added to front of file name

Tags: lyx

I'm not sure what settings I changed and screwed up, but now when I copy a graphic (e.g. "ABC.pdf") from LyX File #1 to LyX File #2, now in LyX File #2, the graphic's "File:" name is changed to to "../ABC.pdf" and as a result the graphic does not correctly show up in LyX File #2. I then have to click on the graphic and change the "File:" name to "ABC.pdf" in order for the graphic to show up.

How do I get back to what it was before (when the graphic "File:" name in LyX file #2 would just be "ABC.pdf" and the graphic would correctly show)?

Comment: Are the .lyx files in different directories? It could be that LyX is trying to give a relative path to the graphic in the other directly, although it appears it might be out-smarting itself.

Comment: No the .lyx files are in the same directory

Comment: Strange. What is the working directory of LyX? I don't know how it works on other OS's, but on Linux if you `cd` to the path and then run `lyx` to start it there, I wonder if that affects things.

Comment: @scottkosty: *What is the working directory of LyX?* > It's just some folder I use for my work. // Do you know what the default Paths (in Preferences) are or where I can find information on this? I think I changed the paths and that's what's causing these problems so I'm wondering if restoring them to the LyX original default paths would help. (But I can't seem to find any information on this and I don't want to reinstall.)

Comment: Good idea. Go to Help > About LyX, then take note of your user directory. then *exit* LyX and open your user directory. There is a file called "preferences" in there. Move the file to somewhere to back it up. Then next time you start LyX it will have default preferences. If you don't exit LyX before you move the file, LyX might write the file on exit.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was restoring Paths (under Tools > Preferences) to their defaults.

See scottkosty's comment above for how to find these defaults.

In my case (using Windows 11) these were the defaults:

[image]

Working directory: C:\Users\XXX\Documents [Replace XXX with your username]

Document templates: C:\Program Files\LyX 2.3\Resources\templates

Example Files: C:\Program Files\LyX 2.3\Resources\examples\

Backup directory: [Leave this blank]

LyXServer pipe: [Leave this blank]

Temporary directory: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp [Replace XXX with your username]

Thesaurus dictionaries: [Leave this blank]

Hunspell dictionaries: [Leave this blank]

PATH prefix: C:\texlive\2022\bin\win32;$LyXDir\bin;$LyXDir\Python;$LyXDir\Python\Lib;$LyXDir\imagemagick;$LyXDir\ghostscript\bin

TEXINPUTS prefix: .

Comment: It seems that a version of the bug still arises if the copy-paste of a graphic is done while running "Export [PDF (pdflatex)]". (LyX may then add some weird long directory name in front of the "ABC.pdf". I think this is some temporary directory.)